# How to install specific Firefox ESR v. 78 ubuntu desktop

Tags: software-installation, firefox, .desktop, mozilla

I'm new to Ubuntu / Linux. How to install a specific Firefox ESR version?

I want to install https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/78.0.1esr/

and don’t know how. I’m using the ubuntu desktop 21.10 64bit on my Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: Please be specific with details; (by *newest* Ubuntu Desktop I take it you mean Ubuntu 21.10 or the 2021-October release), but your mention of *rpi imager* makes me think of *armhf* or *arm64* where the link you provide can provide only other architectures (*i386* or *amd64*).  Please clarify your OS & release as details you've provided show *clash*.

Comment: Hi @guiverc, thanks for you reply. Yes, you are right. I’m using the ubuntu desktop 21.10 64bit on my Raspberry Pi 4. Which architecture shown here https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/78.0.1esr/ will work with my RPI Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 for the *pi* in 64-bit is *arm64*; the only *linux* versions I see in the link you provided are *i386* (32-bit x86; Debian/Ubuntu call it *i386* whilst in Linux terms it really is *i686*) and *amd64* (64-bit x86_64); neither of which will work on an *arm64* device.  You need an *arm64* binary matching your ARM processor.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use the Ubuntu package manager, `apt`, and install programs using that. `linux: $ sudo apt install firefox-esr` I don't know why you think you need a certain version. Most people will install the one that comes with Ubuntu.

If you install programs from all over, not just the Ubuntu repositories, you'll end up with `franken-Unbuntu`, which is perilous at best!

Comment: I can install the newest ff esr. But I need a specific version.

Comment: Why do you need a certain version of firefox-esr? I would advise you just type the `apt` command as I laid it out for you.

Comment: Because I have corresponding dependencies.

Comment: If you're using a certain version of Ubuntu, it won't install incompatible versions of software. Did you install packages that are not part of your version of Ubuntu? Now you have franken-Ubuntu, cobbled together from different sources. You'll need to describe what exactly you're doing, why you're doing it, and maybe we can still help. But it might be too late! Post all error messages with the commands that produce them.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has instructions on different ways to [install Firefox on Linux](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux). See the section "Install Firefox from Mozilla builds (For advanced users)".

Unless you have specific needs, it is much easier and safer to install the long term edition of Firefox from the repositories (`sudo apt install firefox-esr`).

- That way, you do not manipulate system files directly, so there is no change you damage your system through erroneous actions as root user.
- Dependencies are automatically taken care off.

It is not certain an older binary version of Firefox will work correctly on a current Ubuntu versions. There is always a possibility that current versions of dependencies needed by Firefox do not work well anymore with an older version.